# Display create react app's lint errors in Visual Studio Code with 'react-app'

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, create-react-app

With create react app and Visual Studio Code, I want display errors in editor.
I have followed [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor) tutorial, however getting below error in 'OUTPUT'

```
[Error - 12:41:48 PM] Cannot find module 'eslint-config-react-app' Referenced from: ...../xxxx/.eslintrc
```

**This module is already present in "node_modules"

Comment: Does it show up in your package.json file? I know this is a basic check and you probably mean that when you said "it's in node_modules" but can you double check?

Comment: Also, did you create a file called `.eslintrc` and add in the one line from the guide?

Comment: Lastly, in Visual Studio Code, go to extensions and make sure `ESLint` is installed as an extension.

Comment: no its not there in package.json/ why it should be there. its in cra's hidden zero configuration system. Also manually adding it to in package.json isn't mentioned in documentation as well.

Comment: Did you install the extension in VSCODE?

Comment: yes extension installed also.